# Most declarative approach to extract data from strings

Tags: r

I would like to extract data from strings.

**Input:**

```
d <- c("\n      98.000 € VB\n          \n      99999\n          K9mm999u", 
    "\n      9 € VB\n          \n      89999\n          Di9ß99", 
    "\n      900.000 €\n          \n      89999\n          Aich9ch", 
    "\n      979.000 € VB\n          \n      98999\n          Ni9999rg9", 
    "\n      979.000 €\n          \n      99999\n          F9lk99s99"
    )
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[[1]]
[1] "99999"    "K9mm999u"

[[2]]
[1] "89999"  "Di9ß99"

[[3]]
[1] "89999"   "Aich9ch"

[[4]]
[1] "98999"     "Ni9999rg9"

[[5]]
[1] "99999"     "F9lk99s99"
```

**What i tried:**

```
library(magrittr)
d %>% gsub(pattern = ".*€|VB|\n", replacement = "", fixed = FALSE) %>% 
  trimws %>% strsplit(split = "          ")
```

This would work sometimes, but the part `strsplit(split = "          ")` seems pretty bad.

If its ok i would ask in more General:

I would go with:

```
filter <- function(result) result[sapply(result, nchar) > 0]
d %>% gsub(pattern = ".*€|VB|\n", replacement = "", fixed = FALSE) %>% 
  trimws %>% strsplit(split = " ") %>% lapply(FUN = filter)
```

But is it necessary to define this custom `filter` function.

**Question:**

What is the most declarative approach to yield the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's code, `strsplit` with one or more spaces can be changed to `\\s+`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   gsub(pattern = ".*€|VB|\n", replacement = "", fixed = FALSE) %>% 
   trimws %>% 
   strsplit(split = "\\s+")
#[[1]]
#[1] "99999"    "K9mm999u"

#[[2]]
#[1] "89999"  "Di9ß99"

#[[3]]
#[1] "89999"   "Aich9ch"

#[[4]]
#[1] "98999"     "Ni9999rg9"

#[[5]]
#[1] "99999"     "F9lk99s99"
```

---

Here is another option with `read.table` from `base R` where we read the 'd' into a `data.frame`, extract the first column, use logical recycling vector to subset thee elements, and `split` into a `list` with `asplit`

```
asplit(matrix(read.table(text = d, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$V1[c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), 1)
#[[1]]
#[1] "99999"    "K9mm999u"

#[[2]]
#[1] "89999"  "Di9ß99"

#[[3]]
#[1] "89999"   "Aich9ch"

#[[4]]
#[1] "98999"     "Ni9999rg9"

#[[5]]
#[1] "99999"     "F9lk99s99"
```

---

Or with `regmatches/gregexpr` from `base R`, match either 5 digit numbers (`[0-9]{5}`) or (`|`) alpha numeric characters of length 5 and greater (`[[:alnum:]]{5,}`), extract into a `list`.  The `\\b` refers to word boundary

```
regmatches(d, gregexpr("\\b[0-9]{5}\\b|\\b[[:alnum:]]{5,}\\b", d))
#[[1]]
#[1] "99999"    "K9mm999u"

#[[2]]
#[1] "89999"  "Di9ß99"

#[[3]]
#[1] "89999"   "Aich9ch"

#[[4]]
#[1] "98999"     "Ni9999rg9"

#[[5]]
#[1] "99999"     "F9lk99s99"
```